# C++: Defining class in multiple files

Tags: c++, one-definition-rule

According to [One Definition Rule (ODR)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/One_Definition_Rule):

> In the entire program, an object or non-inline function cannot have
>   more than one definition; if an object or function is used, it must
>   have exactly one definition.

These are my files that I am trying to compile:

A.cpp

```
#include <iostream>
#include "Greet.h"

int main()
{
    greet();
    std::cin.get();
}
```

B.cpp

```
#include "Greet.h"
```

Greet.h

```
#include <iostream>

void greet()
{
    std::cout << "Hello World!" << std::endl;
}
```

I get a linker error as expected:

```
fatal error LNK1169: one or more multiply defined symbols found.
```

But when I put `greet()` function in a class. The code compiles fine and gives the output `Hello World!`.

A.cpp

```
#include <iostream>
#include "Greet.h"

int main()
{
    Greet G;
    G.greet();

    std::cin.get();
}
```

B.cpp

```
#include "Greet.h"
```

Greet.h

```
#include <iostream>

class Greet
{
public:
    void greet()
    {
        std::cout << "Hello World!" << std::endl;
    }
};
```

Why is the linker not complaining about multiple definitions of class `Greet`?

The behavior is the same for both MSVC and g++.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> But when I put `greet()` function in a class. The code compiles fine and gives the output `Hello World!`.

When a member function is defined inside a class definition, `inline` is implied. That is not so for non-member functions.

From the [C++ Standard, class.mfct](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n3337/class.mfct#2):

> A member function may be defined ([dcl.fct.def]) in its class definition, in which case it is an *inline* member function ([dcl.fct.spec]), or it may be defined outside of its class definition if it has already been declared but not defined in its class definition.

Comment: So, if I define every function as a member function in class then I won't have any problem with linking? So, why is it recommended to separate C++ class declaration and defintion into separate header and cpp files?

Comment: @AdityaVerma, implementing member functions in a .cpp allows you the flexibility of changing the implementation without changing the header file -- a basic principle of encapsulation.

Comment: Why don't we want to change the header file? I cannot understand how it relates to encapsulation.

Comment: @AdityaVerma, this is not the right place to answer that question. Please browse the net, find and read a good book on software engineering, or post a question at https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/

Comment: Here is a rationale behind the separation of classes into headers and source files: https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/a/320036/338457